# JSDOM.serialize() stripping closing link tags

Tags: javascript, jsdom, create-react-app

I am writing a script for my react app build because I need to modify the index.html that gets created a bit. So I make my modifications using jsdom then pass `dom.serialize()` into fs.writeFile() to write my modifications back to index.html.

This ALMOST gives me what I want, but it ends up looking like this:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="./static/css/main.fed2fd6d.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./indexBody.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/2.be491123.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.9c71d46b.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Where all the link tags have `/>` taken off the ends of them, which will make me have to manually add them each time... I tried passing the jsdom.serialize into parse5 which would then go back to xmlserializer. This preserved the '/>' at the end but changed the script tags to end in `/>` instead of `</script>`, causing them not to load on my page...

Does anyone know how I might preserve the closing tags on the link elements with jsdom?

Comment: I've never used jsdom, but that is valid HTML5 markup from what I am seeing.

Comment: wait, links work with or without the closing tag??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: took me a good minute to adjust too, coming from XHTML.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is what I get for just assuming :/ lol. Thanks for saving me time!